# Is it possible to use countif to count only cells in a range that are at a certain time, regardless of the date

Tags: excel

So lets say i this set of data and i only want to count if the time is 00:00:00 regardless of the date.

I have tried a few things so far that haven't seemed to work such as wildcards, and using the decimal value but nothing i have tried seems to have worked so far.

[image: Using this data as an example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have alluded to, date/time values are store as numbers, with the integral part representing the date, and the decimal part representing the time. so a date with no time would be equal to the int() of the date.

You can build up your solution by creating an IF statement for the first cell which returns 1 if the value = INT(value), or 0 otherwise, and then use the `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` ninja technique to achieve what you want.

So assuming that your dates start in cell A1,

1. Enter `=SUM(IF(A1-INT(A1)=0,1,0))` where you want your total to appear. This will return 0 for your example.
2. Edit the formula to change each of the A1 cell references so that they refer to the range of cells containing the dates. In your example this would be A1:A8. So your formula will now be `=SUM(IF(A1:A8-INT(A1:A8)=0,1,0))`
3. Instead of pressing Enter (which will cause an error), Hold down Ctrl and Shift, then press Enter.
4. A set of curly braces will appear around your formula, and the value of the cell will be the sum of all the IF statements that equal 1, i.e. the count of all dates that don't have a time component.

Here's a [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/CSE-array-formulas-excel.php) to some more info on array formulas (the less-sexy name for "Ctrl-Shift-Enter ninja technique")

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem for me. One thing though if anyone else sees this is the range should be

A1:A8 not A1:A11 as it will count the empty cells as having no time value so you won't get the right answer.

Comment: Thx. Fixed now. I originally copied in the formula from my spreadsheet where I had 11 dates and forgot to change to match ur example.

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping, it's easy to change for other times as well

6AM for example is

=SUM(IF(A1:A8-INT(A1:A8)=0.25,1,0))

for anyone who wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A>0)*(MOD(A:A,1)=0))
```

seems to work.